# Converting RDLC ReportViewer reports created in older versions of Visual Studio to work in newer versions of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, reportviewer

I have looked all over and cannot seem to find an answer.

I recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2008 to 2017. I was able to install ReportViewer on 2017, however, if I open reports that were created in VS 2008, I am asked to convert to the new version.

Once they are converted, I get the error Unknown Report Version: 9.0 for every report.

This has occurred with multiple applications and I had to re-create the reports in one application in order for them to work with VS 2017. Has anyone run into this?

Comment: Hi, I've just run into a similar situation.  Were you able to find a resolution?

Comment: I had to open the reports in VS 2015, upgraded them, and was then able to open them in VS 2017 and upgrade them again.